# Number of solution of a linear diophantine equation

Tags: combinatorics, linear-diophantine-equations

Let $k>n\ge1$. Let then $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be integers $\ge1$.

How can we compute the number of solution of 
$$
x_1+\cdots+x_n=k\;\;\;\;\;\;?
$$
I think combinatoric could help but I don't know how.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Please have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory), there are a couple of algorithms there to solve this problem

Comment: @caverac partitions generally do not concern themselves with the order of the part sizes, the only partitions of $4$ for example are $4,3+1,2+2,2+1+1,1+1+1+1$.  They do not consider $1+2+1$ to be different.  Here however, the tuple $(2,1,1)$ is considered different than $(1,2,1)$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for clarifying this

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard problem of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  Represent each solution as a sequence of stars and bars.  $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(2,1,3,3)$ for example would be represented as $\star\star\mid\star\mid\star\star\star\mid\star\star\star$.  Recognize now that due to the condition that each $x_i$ be at least one that bars cannot be placed next to one another and cannot be placed at the ends.  Place your $k$ stars in a row first and then pick which spaces between the stars have bars in them.

A total of $k$ stars will be used.  A total of $n-1$ bars will be used.  There are $k-1$ spaces between stars available for bars to be in.

> There are then $\binom{k-1}{n-1}$ valid sequences of stars and bars.  We see that these are in direct bijection with the Diophantine solutions of the system.